# How can I catch which task deletes my files?

Tags: windows-10

I have installed a software and different users can upload the sandbox and my PC compiles and links the C code of the sandbox. In the sandbox exist some python und perl scripts for postprocessing.
Some times the instalation of my software tools goes defect because someone deletes some files.
How can I montitor who tried to access these files?

I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SysInternals SysMon for this, it creates an Event Viewer event for file deletion

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon#event-id-23-filedelete-a-file-delete-was-detected